# Memory efficient sliding() function in Java ( analogue to Scala sliding() )

Tags: java, scala, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I'm trying to write memory efficient sliding() method. Here is simple example that showing what is slides:

```
public void sliding() {
    final LinkedList<String> strings = new LinkedList<>();
    strings.add("a");
    strings.add("b");
    strings.add("c");
    strings.add("d");
    strings.add("e");
    strings.add("f");

    final LinkedList<String> slide = new LinkedList<>();
    final int size = strings.size();

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (j + i < size) {
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int k = j; k < i + j; k++) {
                    builder.append(" ").append(strings.get(k));
                }
                slide.add(builder.toString().trim());
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("slide = " + slide);
}
```

As input we have [a,b,c,d,e,f], as output we have all possible slides:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, a b, b c, c d, d e, e f, a b c, b c d, c d e, d e f, a b c d, b c d e, c d e f, a b c d e, b c d e f]
```

I want to write function, that takes `array` and `slidesSize` as argument and return all slides of this `array` with length=`slidesSize`. Here is sample:

```
private LinkedList<String> sliding(LinkedList<String> strings, int slidesSize) {
    final int size = strings.size();
    final LinkedList<String> slides = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j <= size; j++) {
        if (j + slicesSize <= size) {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int k = j; k < slidesSize + j; k++) {
                builder.append(" ").append(strings.get(k));
            }
            slides.add(builder.toString().trim());
        }
    }
    return slides;
}
```

The current problem is, if I'm trying to compute all slides for this `strings`:

```
    final LinkedList<String> strings = new LinkedList<>();
    final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
        final String e = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
        strings.add(e);
    }
```

I'm getting:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
```

Comment: Actually in scala the slice method return, as its name suggest, [slice](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@slice(from:Int,until:Int):List[A]) of the collection, and not add the permutations.

Comment: In Scala this function is called `sliding`

Comment: [sliding](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@sliding(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]) does not exactly do that, but it can be implemented easily: `def slideAll(str: String) = (1 to str.length).flatMap { i => str.sliding(i,1) }`

Comment: Since the result will be huge, you have two options: 1. increase the jvm heap, 2. use iterator instead of LinkedList

Comment: @Kolmar you are right, thanks! I update question

Comment: @roterl is there any idea to use Streams? Could you please give me example with Iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not use `LinkedList`. Use `ArrayList` which is in 99% of cases (including your one) is more efficient both in terms of CPU and memory.

Next thing is to generate slides on the fly instead of storing them in the memory. Here's an example implementation involving the `AbstractList`:

```
static List<String> sliding(final List<String> strings, final int slidesSize) {
    final int size = strings.size();
    if(size < slidesSize)
        return Collections.emptyList();
    return new AbstractList<String>() {
        @Override
        public String get(int j) {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int k = j; k < slidesSize + j; k++) {
                if(k > j) builder.append(' ');
                builder.append(strings.get(k));
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return size - slidesSize+1;
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
final List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
    final String e = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    strings.add(e);
}

for(String slide : sliding(strings, 100)) {
    System.out.println(slide);
}
```

If you want a Java-8 solution, you can easily generate the stream of slides:

```
int slideSize = 100;
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, strings.size()-slideSize)
        .mapToObj(idx -> String.join(" ", strings.subList(idx, idx+slideSize)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note the usage of good old `List.subList` method with new `String.join`.